# From a list of (x,y) pairs, generate a new list of (x,ymean) pairs, where ymean is the average of all y's with the same x in the original list

Tags: list-manipulation, data

This seems like the sort of thing where *Mathematica* can give a very simple solution.

I have a list of points `{x,y}`:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}
```

From this list, I want to generate a new list of pairs `{x,ymean}`, where `ymean` is the average of all `y`'s in the original list which were paired to the same value of `x`:

```
{{1, 3}, {2, 7/2}, {3, 5}}
```

What's the simplest, most elegant way to accomplish this in Mathematica?

Comment: Something involving `GatherBy[list, First]`, I expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have your `2D` list in a variable named `lis`, then the following should work:

```
Mean /@ GatherBy[lis, First]
```

Comment: +1 I knew my solution was too complicated...

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace[GatherBy[data, First], d_List :> {First@First@d, Mean[d[[All, 2]]]}, {1}]
```

where `data` is the original list of points.